# How to git clone a private repo with a private submodule in a GitHub Action?

Tags: github, github-actions, git-submodules

I have two private GitHub repositories within my organisation (or my user). One of them contains the other as a submodule. How can I clone this other private repository with its containing submodule?

I tried

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    submodules: true
```

However this failed with an error message on the submodule part, is there some permission I should add or other?

```
Fetching submodules
  /usr/bin/git submodule sync
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1
  Submodule '.github/workflows/MYPROJECT1' (https://github.com/MYUSER/MYPROJECT1.git) registered for path '.github/workflows/MYPROJECT1'
  Cloning into '/home/runner/work/MYPROJECT2/MYPROJECT2/.github/workflows/MYPROJECT1'...
  remote: Repository not found.
  Error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MYUSER/MYPROJECT1.git/' not found
  Error: fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/MYUSER/MYPROJECT1.git' into submodule path '/home/runner/work/MYPROJECT2/MYPROJECT2/.github/workflows/MYPROJECT1' failed
  Failed to clone '.github/workflows/MYPROJECT1'. Retry scheduled
  ... more errors
```

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/287 ?

Answer (score 6):

You can try and use an SSH URL instead.

The [issue 116 "private submodule checkout fails"](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/116) now (July 2022) illustrates that as an alternative:

> This solution works when you want to keep flexibility of URL repos and still use GitHub Actions with Deploy Keys to access private submodules:

```yaml
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Clone Submodule
    run: |
        mkdir -p $HOME/.ssh
        echo '${{ secrets.SUBMODULE_REPO_DEPLOY_KEY }}' > $HOME/.ssh/ssh.key
        chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/ssh.key
        export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/ssh.key"
        git submodule set-url <path-to-submodule> git@github.com:<organization/submodule>.git
        git submodule update --init --recursive
        git submodule set-url <path-to-submodule> https://github.com/<organization/submodule>.git
        unset GIT_SSH_COMMAND
```

---

[Issue 287](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/#issuecomment-1398500696) ("Support private repositories and private submodule") also includes:

> You can use [`webfactory/ssh-agent` action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/webfactory-ssh-agent) to provide individual deploy keys for multiple submodule repositories like so:
>
> ```yaml
>    ...
>        steps:
>          - uses: actions/checkout@v3
>
>          - name: Add SSH private keys for submodule repositories
>            uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
>            with:
>              ssh-private-key: |
>                ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_SUBMODULE_1 }}
>                ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_SUBMODULE_2 }}
>
>          - run: git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
>    ...
> ```
>
> This worked for me, except that `--remote` was causing it to checkout the incorrect ref (`master` of the submodule, not the referenced commit).
> Just doing `git submodule update --init --recursive` got me the desired behavior

And this [comment confirms](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/287#issuecomment-1427912777) the ssh-agent approach.

---

The previously mentioned [issue 116](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/116#issuecomment-1914873055) also includes:

> This worked for me. After checking out the main repository, my pipeline runs this action to checkout any submodules. It's a little bit hacky, but it has worked for me.
>
> ```yaml
> - name: Checkout the repo
>         uses: actions/checkout@v3.1.0
>         with:
>           persist-credentials: false
>
> - name: Checkout submodule
>         run: |
>           git submodule sync --recursive
>           git -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --depth=1 --recursive
> ```

Comment: Does the first of the two suggested approaches also work for windows workflows, or is it specific to linux?

Comment: @AmosEgel SSH operations are supported on a Windows runner, but path (like `/usr/bin`) or environment variables (like `$HOME`) would need to be translated to their Windows counterpart.